# How to Pause/Resume a process in Linux

Tags: linux, vlc, libvlc

I record my program until it closes.

Start Command:

```
cvlc screen:// --screen-left=0 --screen-top=0 --screen-width=1280 --screen-height=960 --screen-fps=30 \
--sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp2v, vb=800, scale=1, acodec=none}:file{mux=ts, dst=your_video_path_to_be_saved}'
```

Stop Command:

```
kill -9 pgrep vlc
```

That works well, now I need to implement pause method to this program. I need to kill program at pause method then start it on resume method and append new video to older one. How can i do it?

[VLC Wiki: Merge](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_Merge_and_Transcode_Multiple_Videos/)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: Doesn’t the ‘stop’ command need to be `kill -9 $(pgrep vlc)` - or perhaps better, use `pidof` instead of `pgrep`? Or you can do away with the process searching step and use `killall`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To pause the process

```
kill -STOP <PID>
```

To resume it

```
kill -CONT <PID>
```

Comment: Just for pedantry, the signal names this sends to the process in question are SIGSTOP and SIGCONT.

Answer (score 21):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> (SIGTSTP) from the shell stops (nowaday we will probably use the term "suspend", which the man page of bash does) a process. The process can be continued ("resumed") with the commands `fg` (in foreground) or `bg` (in background).

`kill -9` doesn't *stop* a process, it *kills* it (SIGKILL). I mention it, because wording here is ambiguous.